# How does splitting a matrix in blocks improve cache hits?

Tags: caching, matrix

I am trying to understand the concepts of caches and blocking in matrix. I am trying to transpose a matrix.

I understand the concept of row-wise memory layout, so I get that when I am trying to access the data row-wise, I get fewer cache-misses as compared to column wise.

```
  for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )

    for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )

      destination[j+i*n] = source[i+j*n];
```

So for the source matrix, I will have fewer cache misses, while for destination I will have more cache misses.

---

Here is code with blocking

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += blocksize) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j += blocksize) {
        // transpose the block beginning at [i,j]
        for (int k = i; k < i + blocksize; ++k) {
            for (int l = j; l < j + blocksize; ++l) {
                dst[k + l*n] = src[l + k*n];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above makes use of blocking technique. I can't quite understand how does blocking help with the performance?

Comment: I can't claim to understand the algorithmic performance optimization using cache, but Prof. Demaine has [quite a few](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-design-and-analysis-of-algorithms-spring-2015/lecture-videos/) lectures on the subject. Maybe they will help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll have more cache hits on one side than on the other.

The trick, though is to break it into small enough pieces, so that, they can be 'reused' while processing.

[image: Matrices]

E.g. in the example above, we'll have 1 cache miss on src matrix and 4 on dst size (I've picked cache line size of 4 elements and block size of 4 elements, but that's just coincidence).

If the cache size is greater than 5 lines, we will have no more misses while processing the line.

If the cache size is smaller than that, there will be more misses as the lines will be crowding out each other. In this case src will stay in cache as more used and dst one's will be dropped thus giving us 16 misses on dst side. 5 looks better than 17 :)

So by controlling the size of the block being low enough, we can have reduce cache miss rate.

Comment: Can you explain what do we mean block size? There is block in reality in cache, right? It is just our representation.

Comment: Block size is the `blocksize` from your algorithm. That's the size of the sub-matrix we're working with

Minimal cacheable block in cache is called cache line.

Answer (score 0):

The most important aspect here is **locality**, in particular for your example **spatial locality**. Rougly speaking this means to access data that is close to each other.

Whenever one element of the matrix is accssed, and it is not yet in the cache, it always loads the **entire cache line**. This cache line can for example contain 64 byte or 16 integer elements. If you do not use the other elements while they are in cache, your code is inefficient.

The cache line will be evicted, if you load too much data in-between the accesses. Consider the first access from the inner loop which loads `source[i]`. The next element in memory `source[i + 1]` is on the same cache line and was already loaded. However, it will only be needed after the entire inner loop is completed. If the inner loop accesses too much data, `source[i + 1]` won't be in the cache any more. The *distance* between accessing `source[i]` and `source[i+1]` is too large.

Blocking removes this inefficiency. The innermost loop is much smaller than originally, the *distance* between accessing is reduced. All data handled by the innermost loop fits into the cache.